# Asynchronous call to MATLAB's engEvalString

Tags: c++, api, matlab

**Edit 2:** Problem solved, see my answer.

I am writing a C++ program that communicates with MATLAB through the [Engine API](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-engine.html). The C++ application is running on Windows 7, and interacting with MATLAB 2012b (32-bit).

I would like to make a time-consuming call to the MATLAB engine, using `engEvalString`, but cannot figure out how to make the call asynchronous. No callback is necessary (but would be nice if possible).

The following is a minimum example of what doesn't work.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

extern "C" {
    #include <engine.h>
}

int main()
{
    Engine* eng = engOpen("");
    engEvalString(eng,"x=10");
    boost::thread asyncEval(&engEvalString,eng,"y=5");
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
    return 0;
}
```

After running this program, I switch to the MATLAB engine window and find:

```
» x
x =
    10
» y
Undefined function or variable 'y'.
```

So it seems that the second call, which should set y=5, is never processed by the MATLAB engine.

The thread definitely runs, you can check this by moving the `engEvalString` call into a local function and launching this as the thread instead.

I'm really stumped here, and would appreciate any suggestions!

**EDIT:** As Shafik pointed out in his answer, the engine is not thread-safe. I don't think this should be an issue for my use case, as the calls I need to make are ~5 seconds apart, for a calculation that takes 2 seconds. The reason I cannot wait for this calculation, is that the C++ application is a "medium-hard"-real-time robot controller which should send commands at 50Hz. If this rate drops below 30Hz, the robot will assume network issues and close the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out the problem, but would love it if someone could explain **why**!

The following works:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

extern "C" {
#include <engine.h>
}

void asyncEvalString()
{
    Engine* eng = engOpen("");
    engEvalString(eng,"y=5");
}

int main()
{
    Engine* eng = engOpen("");
    engEvalString(eng,"x=10");
    boost::thread asyncEvalString(&asyncEvalString);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    engEvalString(eng,"z=15");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, you need to get a new pointer to the engine in the new thread. The pointer returned in `asyncEvalString` is different to the original pointer returned by `engOpen` in the main function, however both pointers continue to operate without problem:

```
» x
x =
    10
» y
y =
     5
» z
z =
    15
```

Finally, to tackle the problem of thread safety, a mutex could be set up around the engEvalString calls to ensure only one thread uses the engine at any one time. The asyncEvalString function could also be modified to trigger a callback function once the engEvalString function has been completed.

I would however appreciate someone explaining why the above solution works. Threads share heap allocated memory of the process, and can access memory on other threads' stacks (?), so I fail to understand why the first `Engine*` was suddenly invalid when used in a separate thread.

Comment: I'd just like to add that a call to engOpen("") takes a relatively long time, so when possible, Engine* should be cached for reuse in the same thread. If I cache the value for synchronous calls, I can achieve a loop rate of 50Hz (with a lot of other complex processing happening, this is roughly the limit of my laptop), if I get a new engine for every call, I can only achieve 25Hz.

Answer (score 1):

So according to this Mathworks document it is not thread safe so I doubt this will work:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-engine.html

and according to this document, engOpen forks a new process which would probably explain the rest of the behavior you are seeing:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/engopen.html

Also see, threads and forks, think twice about mixing them:

http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Comment: Good point regarding thread safety, however the calculation calls I need to make to MATLAB are spaced ~5 seconds apart, the reason it needs to be asynchronous is that the program (controller for a robot) needs to send commands every 20ms and can't wait for the calculation to finish.